# maps api v2 android: Binary XML file line #2 error

Tags: java, android, xml, api, google-maps

I have been toiling with the Google-maps API for Android v2 for days now, and cannot figure out how to get this activity working, here is the layout file activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:id="@+id/map"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>
```

Here is MainActivity.java:

package com.gabe.locator;

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

And my manifest file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.gabe.locator"
        android:versionCode="1"
        android:versionName="1.0" >

        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
      <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
      <!-- The following two permissions are not required to use
           Google Maps Android API v2, but are recommended. -->
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
        <uses-feature
            android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
            android:required="true"/>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyDW3bQEXEHW956EiLMhgvaXBQMakRa7i6E" />

        <uses-sdk
            android:minSdkVersion="12"
            android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

        <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
            <activity
                android:name="com.gabe.locator.MainActivity"
                android:label="@string/app_name" >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
        </application>

    </manifest>
```

here is my last error trace:

```
02-06 21:02:57.406: D/AndroidRuntime(29553): Shutting down VM
    02-06 21:02:57.406: W/dalvikvm(29553): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4162a7c0)
    02-06 21:02:57.416: E/AndroidRuntime(29553): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    02-06 21:02:57.416: E/AndroidRuntime(29553): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.gabe.locator/com.gabe.locator.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class fragment
    02-06 21:02:57.416: E/AndroidRuntime(29553):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2339)
    02-06 21:02:57.416: E/AndroidRuntime(29553):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2389)
    02-06 21:02:57.416: E/AndroidRuntime(29553):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:153)
    02-06 21:02:57.416: E/AndroidRuntime(29553):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1269)
    02-06 21:02:57.416: E/AndroidRuntime(29553):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    02-06 21:02:57.416: E/AndroidRuntime(29553):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    02-06 21:02:57.416: E/AndroidRuntime(29553):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5289)
    02-06 21:02:57.416: E/AndroidRuntime(29553):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    02-06 21:02:57.416: E/AndroidRuntime(29553):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
    02-06 21:02:57.416: E/AndroidRuntime(29553):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:739)
    02-06 21:02:57.416: E/AndroidRuntime(29553):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:555)
    02-06 21:02:57.416: E/AndroidRuntime(29553):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    02-06 21:02:57.416: E/AndroidRuntime(29553): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class fragment
    02-06 21:02:57.416: E/AndroidRuntime(29553):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:713)
    02-06 21:02:57.416: E/AndroidRuntime(29553):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:469)
    02-06 21:02:57.416: E/AndroidRuntime(29553):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
    02-06 21:02:57.416: E/AndroidRuntime(29553):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
    02-06 21:02:57.416: E/AndroidRuntime(29553):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:320)
    02-06 21:02:57.416: E/AndroidRuntime(29553):  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1895)
    02-06 21:02:57.416: E/AndroidRuntime(29553):  at com.gabe.locator.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:12)
    02-06 21:02:57.416: E/AndroidRuntime(29553):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
    02-06 21:02:57.416: E/AndroidRuntime(29553):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
    02-06 21:02:57.416: E/AndroidRuntime(29553):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2293)
    02-06 21:02:57.416: E/AndroidRuntime(29553):  ... 11 more
    02-06 21:02:57.416: E/AndroidRuntime(29553): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: A required meta-data tag in your app's AndroidManifest.xml does not exist.  You must have the following declaration within the <application> element:     <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    02-06 21:02:57.416: E/AndroidRuntime(29553):  at com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.n(Unknown Source)
    02-06 21:02:57.416: E/AndroidRuntime(29553):  at com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(Unknown Source)
    02-06 21:02:57.416: E/AndroidRuntime(29553):  at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.q.v(Unknown Source)
    02-06 21:02:57.416: E/AndroidRuntime(29553):  at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.q.u(Unknown Source)
    02-06 21:02:57.416: E/AndroidRuntime(29553):  at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapsInitializer.initialize(Unknown Source)
    02-06 21:02:57.416: E/AndroidRuntime(29553):  at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment$b.eb(Unknown Source)
    02-06 21:02:57.416: E/AndroidRuntime(29553):  at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment$b.a(Unknown Source)
    02-06 21:02:57.416: E/AndroidRuntime(29553):  at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a.a(Unknown Source)
    02-06 21:02:57.416: E/AndroidRuntime(29553):  at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a.onInflate(Unknown Source)
    02-06 21:02:57.416: E/AndroidRuntime(29553):  at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment.onInflate(Unknown Source)
    02-06 21:02:57.416: E/AndroidRuntime(29553):  at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4745)
    02-06 21:02:57.416: E/AndroidRuntime(29553):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:689)
    02-06 21:02:57.416: E/AndroidRuntime(29553):  ... 20 more
    02-06 21:03:00.530: I/Process(29553): Sending signal. PID: 29553 SIG: 9
```

Does anyone have any idea what is causing the crash each time I run this on Cyanogenmod for HTC One S, with android 4.3.1?

Thanks!
Gabe

Answer (score 2):

As per [Documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/map)

> **Note:** The Google Maps Android API requires API level 12 or higher for
>   the support of **MapFragment** objects. If you are targeting an
>   application earlier than API level 12, you can access the same
>   functionality through the **SupportMapFragment** class. You will also have
>   to include the **Android Support Library**.

Add this both

```
  <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyDW3bQEXEHW956EiLMhgvaXBQMakRa7i6E" />
```

Under `<application>` tag in `manifest.xml` file.

And `extends` your `Activity` to `FragmentActivity`.

Answer (score 0):

Use SupportMapFragment in layout.xml

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
```

Also extend as FragmentActivity and not as Activity